# EditableGrid fails to load inline json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, user-interface, editablegrid

I'm trying to use [EditableGrid](https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid) with data in json format that is inside the script itself, but I'm getting error messages.

This is using the latest code from Github so it's supposedly version 3.0

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Code sample:

```
var jsonData = {
    "metadata":[
        {"name":"name","label":"NAME","datatype":"string","editable":true},
        {"name":"firstname","label":"FIRSTNAME","datatype":"string","editable":true},
        {"name":"age","label":"AGE","datatype":"integer","editable":true},
        {"name":"height","label":"HEIGHT","datatype":"double(m,2)","editable":true},
        {"name":"country","label":"COUNTRY","datatype":"string","editable":true,"values":
            {
                "Europe":{"be":"Belgium","fr":"France","uk":"Great-Britain","nl":"Nederland"},
                "America":{"br":"Brazil","ca":"Canada","us":"USA"},
                "Africa":{"ng":"Nigeria","za":"South-Africa","zw":"Zimbabwe"}}
            },
        {"name":"email","label":"EMAIL","datatype":"email","editable":true},
        {"name":"freelance","label":"FREELANCE","datatype":"boolean","editable":true},
        {"name":"lastvisit","label":"LAST VISIT","datatype":"date","editable":true}
    ],

    "data":[
        {"id":1, "values":{"country":"uk","age":33,"name":"Duke","firstname":"Patience","height":1.842,"email":"patience.duke@gmail.com","lastvisit":"11\/12\/2002"}},
        {"id":2, "values":["Rogers","Denise",59,1.627,"us","rogers.d@gmail.com","","07\/05\/2003"]},
        {"id":3, "values":{"name":"Dujardin","firstname":"Antoine","age":21,"height":1.73,"country":"fr","email":"felix.compton@yahoo.fr","freelance":true,"lastvisit":"21\/02\/1999"}},
        {"id":4, "values":{"name":"Conway","firstname":"Coby","age":47,"height":1.96,"country":"za","email":"coby@conwayinc.com","freelance":true,"lastvisit":"01\/12\/2007"}},
        {"id":5, "values":{"name":"Shannon","firstname":"Rana","age":24,"height":1.56,"country":"nl","email":"ranna.shannon@hotmail.com","freelance":false,"lastvisit":"07\/10\/2009"}},
        {"id":6, "values":{"name":"Benton","firstname":"Jasmine","age":61,"height":1.71,"country":"ca","email":"jasmine.benton@yahoo.com","freelance":false,"lastvisit":"13\/01\/2009"}},
        {"id":7, "values":{"name":"Belletoise","firstname":"AndrÃ©","age":31,"height":1.84,"country":"be","email":"belletoise@kiloutou.be","freelance":true,"lastvisit":""}},
        {"id":8, "values":{"name":"Santa-Maria","firstname":"Martin","age":37,"height":1.80,"country":"br","email":"martin.sm@gmail.com","freelance":false,"lastvisit":"12\/06\/1995"}},
        {"id":9, "values":{"name":"Dieumerci","firstname":"AmÃ©dÃ©","age":37,"height":1.81,"country":"ng","email":"dieumerci@gmail.com","freelance":true,"lastvisit":"05\/07\/2009"}},
        {"id":10,"values":{"name":"Morin","firstname":"Wanthus","age":46,"height":1.77,"country":"zw","email":"morin.x@yahoo.json.com","freelance":false,"lastvisit":"04\/03\/2004"}}
    ]};

$(function() {
    editableGrid = new EditableGrid("EdiTable");
    editableGrid.load(jsonData);
    editableGrid.renderGrid("tablecontent");
});
```

The html code contains a div with `id=tablecontent`

Answer (score 3):

I guess the error message you got is something like :

> Who is calling me now ? 
>   EditableGrid.prototype.init@http://www.editablegrid.net/templates/editablegrid_2015/js/editablegrid/editablegrid.js:168:15
>   EditableGrid@http://www.editablegrid.net/templates/editablegrid_2015/js/editablegrid/editablegrid.js:121:49
>   @file:///home/michel/a.html:45:20
>   n.Callbacks/j@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:26855
>   n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:27673
>   .ready@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29465
>   I@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29656

In such a case it is because some parts of editablegrid are missing.
You should, like in the [demo](http://www.editablegrid.net/en/) include :

```
<!-- include javascript and css files for the EditableGrid library -->
<script src="http://www.editablegrid.net/templates/editablegrid_2015/js/editablegrid/editablegrid.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.editablegrid.net/templates/editablegrid_2015/js/editablegrid/editablegrid_editors.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.editablegrid.net/templates/editablegrid_2015/js/editablegrid/editablegrid_renderers.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.editablegrid.net/templates/editablegrid_2015/js/editablegrid/editablegrid_utils.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.editablegrid.net/templates/editablegrid_2015/js/editablegrid/editablegrid_validators.js"></script>
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Change**.

```
editableGrid.load(jsonData);
```

**To**.

```
editableGrid.load({"metadata": jsonData.metadata, "data": jsonData.data});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/yb24yfkn/)

Comment: I don't see how this is different from what I was doing.  I noticed that your demo is using version 2.0.1 though, are you sure that it will work for 3.0?

Comment: I am not sure about 3.0 ,but I think It should work :)

Answer (score 0):

i got this error when, i passed empty object in data , thus not passing the data to the function.

When i passed proper object, this issue did not come